# How to make $http.post api call to wait till the response is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This is my js script pasted below. When I click the button, it triggers  function btnInitiateAPICall() and it makes the first API call to get the number of users.But with my code it is not waiting for the firstAPI to finish executing and goes to InitiateSecondAPI call. Any one help me correct my code to wait for the first APIcall to finish and then start with my secondAPIcall.

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary left" id="btnSubmit"
        ng-disabled="working" ng-click="btnInitiateAPICall()">
  submit
</button>
<img width="30" height="30" class="progressgif" style="display:none"
     alt="spinner" src="../Images/spinner.gif">
```

```
$scope.btnInitiateAPICall = function () {

            if ($scope.selection == '' || $scope.selection == undefined) {
                alert("Please select one option from dropdown");
                return;
            } else {

               var count=FetchNumberOfMatchingUsers($q, $http) //this call should wait until the count is returned before it goes to next line

                InitiateSecondAPICall(count);

            }

        }


function FetchNumberOfMatchingUsers($q, $http) {
            console.log("starting FetchNumberOfMatchingUsers");
            $('.progressgif').show();
            return $http.post("/api/UserRecords/GetUserCount", {
                Instance: $scope.selection,
            }).then(
            function (response) {
                $scope.count = 0;
                $scope.count = response.data;
                return response.data;
            }
            ).catch(

            function (response) {
                return $q.reject(response);

            });
       $('.progressgif').hide();
        }
```

Comment: perform the second call inside the `then` of the first one `FetchNumberOfMatchingUsers($q, $http).then( // second here)`

Comment: why is ` $('.progressgif').hide();` at the last line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the second call in a `.then` block:

```
$scope.btnInitiateAPICall = function () {

   if ($scope.selection == '' || $scope.selection == undefined) {
        alert("Please select one option from dropdown");
        return;
    } else {

       FetchNumberOfMatchingUsers()
       .then(function(count) {
            //this call should wait until the count is returned before it goes to next line
           InitiateSecondAPICall(count);
       });

    }

}
```